# Activity not receiving Custom Broadcast Intent from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast Receiver (**BackgroundReceiver**) which listen for package removal and then broadcast the package name to an Activity (**AnalyzeActivity**)

***BackgroundReceiver.java***

```
public static final String REMOVED_INTENT = "com.analyze.project.RemovedReceiver";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String actionStr = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equals(actionStr)) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            String pkg = uri != null ? uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;
            Log.i("Logging Service", "Package Removed: " + pkg);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Package Removed:" + pkg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent c = new Intent();
            c.setAction(REMOVED_INTENT);
            c.putExtra("Package", pkg);
            context.sendBroadcast(c);
        }
    }
```

I dynamically register the receivers inside my **AnalyzeActivity** and listen for the custom Broadcast Intent from **BackgroundReceiver**

***AnalyzeActivity.java***

```
    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            // Register Sync Recievers
            IntentFilter intentToReceiveFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentToReceiveFilter.addAction(BackgroundReceiver.REMOVED_INTENT);
            this.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, intentToReceiveFilter, null, mHandler);
            mReceiversRegistered = true;

        }

    final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String Package = intent.getStringExtra("Package");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BackgroundReceiver.REMOVED_INTENT)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "(A) Package Removed: " + Package, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("Package Removed", "(A) Package Removed: " + Package);
            }

        }
    };
```

But my Activity doesn't seem to be able to receive the broadcast intents at all.

Comment: Is the first BR working? (BackgroundReceiver)

Comment: I just tried the you code in dummy project (where I raised the broadcast from the onOptionsItemSelected() method) and it was working fine. Are you able to receive the broadcast for package removal from the system...

Comment: Is your activity(where broadcast is registered) is visible when you receive a custom broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to register broacast in your onResume

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BackgroundReceiver.REMOVED_INTENT);

mIntentReceiver intentToReceiveFilter = new mIntentReceiver();

registerReceiver(intentToReceiveFilter,filter);
```

And use this to send broadcast from the package removal broadcast receiver

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundReceiver.REMOVED_INTENT);
intent.putExtra("Package", pkg);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Please let me know if it solves your problem